# How can i display System Tray or App Icon with electron

Tags: electron.net

Iam trying to add a App Icon to my Electron.Net Application but the Icon isn't Displayed in the Taskbar / System Tray,

What i did:

in electron.manifest.json i have

```
"linux": {
      "icon": "../../../wwwroot/build/icons/256x256.png",
      "category": "Office"
    },
```

in the Startup.cs

```
var window = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(new BrowserWindowOptions{
                Width = 1280,
                Height = 756,
                Fullscreenable= false,
                HasShadow= true,
                AutoHideMenuBar=true,
                Maximizable= false,
                Icon = "../../../wwwroot/build/icons/32x32.png"
                
            });
```

First i checked if the filepath is right and yes its right, i tryed different folders, different filenames but nothing worked.

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1):

To create a tray icon, add this code on your app startup (Startup.cs in your case, Program.cs for NET6) before `app.Run();`:

```
var TrayMenu = new MenuItem[]
{
    new MenuItem{
        Label = "Show window",
        Click = () => { Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First().Show(); }
    },
    new MenuItem{
        Label = "Hide",
        Click = () => { Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First().Hide(); }
    },
    new MenuItem{
        Label = "Quit",
        Click = () => { Electron.App.Exit(0); }
    }
};
Electron.Tray.Show("/your/logo/here.png", TrayMenu);
```

And as to it not showing in taskbar you probably disabled it somewhere in your code, provide more info.
Perhaps it has something to do with your disabled fullscreen/resize thing in Startup.cs?